TV show about group of teens who went into cyberspace and turned into robots
I remember a show about a group of teens who went into cyberspace or something like that and turned into robots. I remember there was also a robot dog and two of the people were raised together at some academy or something and one of them turned evil. I also remember that one of their uncles or grandpas owned a store of some kind.
It was on TV in English in Canada and I saw it somewhere between 2005 and 2012. I'm pretty sure it was live action.

Could it possibly be VR Troopers? Several of your descriptions appear in the intro, the dog, the teens going into the cyberspace zone, etc. Here's the IMDB summary: 

Industrialist Carl Ziktor's virtual alter-ego Grimlord worked on the creation of an army made of warrior robots. And, before he became missing for two years, Ryan Steel's father worked with Professor Hart to prevent Grimlord's efforts by developing the ultimate weapon using the most advanced technology man had ever seen to stop him. Now, with the help of his friends J.B. and Kaitlin, Ryan and his friends use the VR power to prevent Grimlord's army from crossing over into our reality from Virtual Reality--and ruling it. However, will Ryan ever find his father?




